# Swift 3 Change color of selected text in UITextView

Tags: swift3, uitextview, textcolor

I have just changed my code to Swift 3 from swift 2.3. The following code is working fine with swift 2.3 but there is no effect with swift 3.

I want to develop a customise text editor. And let user to select text and change its color. For that i am using this code.

```
let selectedRange = textView.selectedRange

        let currentAttr = textView.textStorage.attributes(at: selectedRange.location, effectiveRange: nil)

        var attrName = NSForegroundColorAttributeName

        if !isForeGround{
            attrName = NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
        }

        if currentAttr[attrName] == nil || currentAttr[attrName] as! UIColor != selectedUIColor{

            let dict = [attrName:selectedUIColor]

            let currentFont = currentAttr[NSFontAttributeName]
            let fontDescriptor = (currentFont! as AnyObject).fontDescriptor
            let updatedFont = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor!, size: 0.0)
            let dict2 = [NSFontAttributeName: updatedFont]

            textView.textStorage.beginEditing()

            if currentAttr.count>0{
                textView.textStorage.addAttributes(dict, range: selectedRange)
            }else{
                textView.textStorage.setAttributes(dict, range: selectedRange)
            }
            textView.textStorage.addAttributes(dict2, range: selectedRange)
            textView.textStorage.endEditing()
        }
```

Runs successfully but there is no effect on text color.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

First you need to catch your selected text, with:

`let selectedText = textView.selectedRange`

Then, you create the attribute:

`let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: selectedUIColor]`

And lastly:

`textView.textStorage.addAttributes(myAttribute, range: selectedText)`

**This must be in an Action called by any sender**

Hope it works also for you!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Selected text can be changed with

```
self.textView.tintColor = .red
```